# Laravel: Imposibble to create directory

Tags: php, laravel, file, directory, root

here is my code to make file in new folder use php without framework

```
    <?php 
$line = file_get_contents("WMLG2_2017_07_11.log", "r");
$fLine = explode("\n", $line);
$size = count($fLine);
$namafile="";
$extension = "txt";
$newfile;
$file = "";
$filenameExtension = "";

for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    if (strpos($fLine[$i], 'root@CLA-0 [WMLG2]  >') !== false) {
        $namafileA = explode('> ', $fLine[$i]);
        $namafile = str_replace(' ', '_', $namafileA[1]);
        $filenameExtension = $namafile.".txt";
        $file = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_.]/', '', $filenameExtension); // hapus special character kecuali "." dan "_"
    } else {
        $newfile = fopen("show_command_file/$file", "a");
        fwrite($newfile, $fLine[$i]."\n");
    }
}
```

and here its my code use laravel framework

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input as Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function upload()
    {
        if(Input::hasFile('file')){
            $file = Input::file('file');
            $file->move('storage',$file->getClientOriginalName());
            $this->separate($file->getClientOriginalName());
            return view('layouts.pages.view_upload',['notice'=>$file->getClientOriginalName()." Uploaded"]);    
        }
    }

    public function separate($filename){
        $line = Storage::get("public/".$filename);
        $fLine = explode("\n", $line);
        $size = count($fLine);
        $namafile="";
        $extension = "txt";
        $newfile;
        $file = "";
        $filenameExtension = "";

        for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
            if (strpos($fLine[$i], 'root@CLA-0 [WMLG2]  >') !== false) {
                $namafileA = explode('> ', $fLine[$i]);
                $namafile = str_replace(' ', '_', $namafileA[1]);
                $filenameExtension = $namafile.".txt";
                $file = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_.]/', '', $filenameExtension); // hapus special character kecuali "." dan "_"
            } else {
                $newfile = Storage::put('public/show_command_file/'.$file, $fLine[$i]."\n");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

when i use this laravel, i got notice "Impossible to create the root directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\grapari\storage\app\public/show_command_file"."

what is the solution? and i cant open storage/public folder in my sublime text.

Comment: Can you use "\" or DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of "/"?

Comment: You can also check if directory exists and if not use `mkdir('show_command_file', 0775);`

Comment: @MargusPala if i write like this "public/cek.txt" the file cek.txt can created but if im use "public/$file" access denied same like "public\.$file"

Comment: @PatrykWoziński im already make the directory, the problem now is when im use name of file as variable